# Improve runtime of function calculating maximum sum of node values in a binary tree

Tags: javascript, tree, binary-tree

The idea is to find the path whose value is greatest (the sum of the value of nodes along this path). EDIT: The nodes are totally unordered, meaning you have to search the whole path to know if one path will have a greater value than another.

Here is the node constructor of the tree:

```
var Node = function(val) {
  this.val = val;
  this.left = null;
  this.right = null;
}
```

Here is the function calculating the max value of paths:

```
function maxPath(top) {
    if (top.right === null || top.left === null) return top.val;
    return Math.max(top.val, Math.max(top.val + maxPath(top.left), top.val + maxPath(top.right)));
}
```

The function is pretty inefficient and will only return an answer reasonably fast ( within a second) for a tree that is about ~25 levels deep. I'm trying to find the max sum path for a tree that's 100 levels deep, can't seem to find my way there. Is there a way to improve runtime?

Answer (score 0):

**Bad answer, because I don't fully understand question**
 
You can store precalculated sum from root to vertex if data of tree is static.

---

**Next attempt**
Try remove recursion.
 
But I think it don't be faster because V8 already optimize your code.

```
function getMaxPath (topNode) {
    var node = topNode; 
    var sum = node.val;
    while (node.right) { // binary tree, right? So rigth and left exists together.
        node = (node.right.val >= node.left.val) ? node.right : node.left;
        sum = node.val;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

---

**Next!**

```
var sums = []; // array of sum for each leaf
topNode.sum = topNode.val;

function fall(node) {
   if (!node.right) 
       return sums.push(node.sum);

   node.right.sum = node.sum + node.right.val;
   fall(node.right);

   node.left.sum = node.sum + node.left.val;
   fall(node.left);
}

fall(topNode);
console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, sums)); // find max
```

Comment: Wouldn't that only improve run time after the second time through? Also, what would be the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: Apologies, I forgot an important distinction - the nodes are completely unordered so simply going down the path where the value of left vs right is great does not guarantee you to find the greatest overall path sum.

Comment: This uses too much memory, I get a heap error. Not sure what else is possible!